# Android ByteArrayBuffer holds more bytes than capacity

Tags: java, android, io, urlconnection

I found the following code in a project. It works and can read more than 20MB big files. From how the code is set up it should fail after 5000 bytes. Why does it work? The docs for ByteArrayBuffer indicate nothing like that. I have verified that the read-loop iterates for all bytes of each file.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/ByteArrayBuffer.html

```
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        ucon.setReadTimeout(10000); // enables throw SocketTimeoutException
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

        long expectedFileSize = ucon.getContentLength();
        Log.d("Downloader", "expected file size: " + expectedFileSize);

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        // Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
        // This code can read 20MB and bigger mp3-files, ... why?!?
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/ByteArrayBuffer.html - "public void append(int b)
Appends b byte to this buffer. The capacity of the buffer is increased, if necessary, to accommodate the additional byte."

Comment: I thought this is the official documentation (it lacks this info) ... http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/ByteArrayBuffer.html Thanks. PS: I got the first OutOfMemory from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5000 is just an initial capacity. It gets resized automatically once reaches its limit

Comment: Shouldn't reading a 20MB file like that ask for trouble on android phones, as it probably is held in RAM Memory and is probably not memory mapped? But it is intriguing to not have to worry about half downloaded contents this way.

Comment: Yep, Android apps tend to sometimes take up a lot of RAM